# In C++ unions, which member destructor gets called by union destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Let's say my C++ class has a private union.

```
class Thingy
{
public:
    explicit Thingy( const std::string & v ); // initializes u.value_
    explicit Thingy( const std::share_ptr & p ); // initializes u.ptr_

    ~Thingy();

    // ... other functions ...

private:

    union Value
    {
        std::string value_;
        std::shared_ptr ptr_;
    };

    enum Tag
    {
        String,
        Pointer
    };

    Tag tag_;
    Value u_;
};
```

When the program calls the implicit destructor for Thingy::Value::~Value(), which member variable's destructor gets called? The one for value_ or the one for ptr_?

How would I guarantee the right one gets called?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690652/how-to-write-destructor-for-union-like-class).

Comment: Neither (`~Value()` should be deleted, in fact). It's your job to destroy the object correctly.

Comment: @ZunTzu and T.C. - Thanks. Got it.